Problema de VSC con Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. No abre
quería saber si peuden ayudarme a resolver esta situación.
Tengo este sistema operativo:
No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Release:    22.04 Codename:   jammy
Hasta la versión 1.85 de VSC me funcionaba correctamente, pero desde que actualizaron a las versionas 1.86 y 1.87, me dejó de funcionar.
Cuando quiero abrir el VSC aparece la ventana pero se cierra.
Al ejecutar:
 code --verbose
me responde:
0404/184407.977213:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir /home/luisfergm/.config/Code/Crashpad/attachments/12a75630-dd23-4ad4-b33b-ef84d5a99e0c: No such file or directory (2)
[49507:0404/184408.068684:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[49537:0404/184408.137016:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49537:0404/184408.137056:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49537:0404/184408.137064:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[49537:0404/184408.137573:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49537:0404/184408.137582:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49537:0404/184408.137588:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[49537:0404/184408.137593:ERROR:gl_display.cc(829)] Initialization of all EGL display types failed.
[49537:0404/184408.137598:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)] GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
[49537:0404/184408.144894:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49537:0404/184408.144907:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49537:0404/184408.144911:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[49537:0404/184408.145348:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49537:0404/184408.145354:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49537:0404/184408.145357:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[49537:0404/184408.145360:ERROR:gl_display.cc(829)] Initialization of all EGL display types failed.
[49537:0404/184408.145363:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)] GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
[49537:0404/184408.146072:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(196)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[main 2024-04-04T21:44:08.183Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Request to start watching: /home/luisfergm/.config/Code/User (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>, correlationId: <none>),/home/luisfergm/.config/Code/User/settings.json (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>, correlationId: <none>)
[main 2024-04-04T21:44:08.196Z] Starting VS Code
[main 2024-04-04T21:44:08.196Z] from: /snap/code/155/usr/share/code/resources/app

libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[49571:0404/184408.215679:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49571:0404/184408.215725:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49571:0404/184408.215731:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[49571:0404/184408.216258:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49571:0404/184408.216267:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49571:0404/184408.216271:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[49571:0404/184408.216276:ERROR:gl_display.cc(829)] Initialization of all EGL display types failed.
[49571:0404/184408.216280:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)] GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
[49571:0404/184408.223923:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49571:0404/184408.223937:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49571:0404/184408.223939:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[49571:0404/184408.224351:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49571:0404/184408.224360:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49571:0404/184408.224363:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[49571:0404/184408.224367:ERROR:gl_display.cc(829)] Initialization of all EGL display types failed.
[49571:0404/184408.224371:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)] GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
[49571:0404/184408.225205:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(196)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[main 2024-04-04T21:44:08.243Z] window#load: attempt to load window (id: 1)
[main 2024-04-04T21:44:08.248Z] windowsManager#open used window count 1 (workspacesToOpen: 0, foldersToOpen: 0, emptyToRestore: 0, emptyToOpen: 1)
[main 2024-04-04T21:44:08.248Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 3)
[main 2024-04-04T21:44:08.248Z] resolveShellEnv(): skipped (VSCODE_CLI is set)
[main 2024-04-04T21:44:08.269Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/luisfergm/.config/Code/User/settings.json'
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[49589:0404/184408.345115:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49589:0404/184408.345173:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49589:0404/184408.345181:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[49589:0404/184408.345760:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49589:0404/184408.345770:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49589:0404/184408.345774:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[49589:0404/184408.345778:ERROR:gl_display.cc(829)] Initialization of all EGL display types failed.
[49589:0404/184408.345782:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)] GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
[49589:0404/184408.353678:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49589:0404/184408.353692:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49589:0404/184408.353695:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[49589:0404/184408.354104:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
ERR: Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49589:0404/184408.354109:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[49589:0404/184408.354112:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[49589:0404/184408.354115:ERROR:gl_display.cc(829)] Initialization of all EGL display types failed.
[49589:0404/184408.354118:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)] GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
[49589:0404/184408.354991:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(196)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0404/184408.398847:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0404/184408.398866:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0404/184408.398871:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[49507:0404/184408.469632:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(995)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[49507:0404/184408.469643:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1364)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)

Estoy buscando información para intentar solucionarlo, pero por el momento no encontré nada, agradecería si alguien puede darme una mano.
Ya intenté:
code --disable-gpu
apt install mesa libglu1-mesa
ldconfig -p | grep libGL
rm -rf /home/luis/.config/Code

sudo apt install mesa-utils
glxinfo -B
sudo apt install -y gpg-agent wget
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme. Muchas gracias.

¿Y si lo instalas via Snap?

Lo tengo instalado desde snap. Y como no se como deshabilitar las actualizaciones automaticas en snap, constantemente me actualiza el "code" a la ultima version. Entonces lo que hago es instalar "manualmente" la version 1.85, con "sudo snap install code-stable-x64-1705562349-v1_85.snap --classic" (tengo descargado el instalador) porque es la que me funciona. Por las dudas, sabes como deshabilitar la actualizacion automatica en snap?

Listo. Lo solucioné usando:
code --disable-accelerated-video-decode

Listo, para los que se encuentran con este problema, lo solucioné usando:
code --disable-accelerated-video-decode 

Referencias:
[https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204159][1]
[https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/212494#issuecomment-2151817989][2]
